# Know certificate signing algorithm of a remote site using OpenSSL

Tags: certificates, openssl

I have been trying to know the "Certificate Signing Algorithm" ( SHA1 with RSA etc.) using openssl.

To start with I tried to see the cerificate using following command, but it also does not show up any signning algorithm details.

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <myhost>:443
```

Is there a way I can know it using a single command ?

Comment: Have you tried [`echo "" | openssl s_client -connect server:port -prexit 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p'`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7886248/3714897)

Comment: yes, it prints the certificates, but how can I know the algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output from `openssl s_client` (which includes the cert in PEM-format) into `openssl x509 -noout -text` and it gives a human-readable display of the cert fields, including the signing algo (in two places). You don't need the `sed -n /BEGIN/,/END/p` step; most OpenSSL operations on PEM-format data, including this one, ignore "extra" data outside the PEM block. (This is NOT true for many other programs though.) `-showcerts` is useless in this case, since only the first cert, which is the server cert, is displayed.

To be exact, this is the signing algo used *on* the server's cert *by* the CA who issued the cert. It isn't performed or even directly controlled by the server.

If you want to look at the **whole chain** not just the server cert, you *do* need `-showcerts` and you need to run `openssl x509 ...` separately on *each* cert; a simple but somewhat crude way is

```
echo | openssl s_client ... | \
awk 'BEGIN{p="openssl x509 -noout -text"} {print |p} /-----END/{close(p)}'
```